# mvvm backgroundworker - CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm

I am having an issue where my backgroundworker completes the work the first time I press the button that calls it but the second time I press the button an error is generated.  The error is flagged on an integer not on a collection.

The error is "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."  The code line is " t += 1;"  Maybe I need to define the backgroundworker in a different spot?
Here is part of the code.

```
       public P4LabelBatteryViewModel()
    {
        BatteryCheckerModel BatteryCheckerModel = new BatteryCheckerModel();

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_WorkerCompleted;

    }
     private void checkOutRestults()
    {
        TotalFiles = 0;

        foreach (var _scripObject in ScriptCollection)
        {
            if (_scripObject.ScriptNameAdd != "")
            {
                TotalFiles += 1;
            }
        }

        if (ScriptCollection.Count > 0)
        {
                        _isrunning = true;
                        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }  
    }
       void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.ProgressPercentage;
        NewBatteryFiles += 1;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptModel _newFileResult = new ScriptModel();
        int t = 0;

        _newFileResult = CheckOutResults.CheckOutResultBatteryFiles(BatteryLocation, SelectedMachine.Machine);
        ScriptCollectionTemp.Add(_newFileResult);
        t += 1;

        foreach (ScriptModel _checkOutFile in ScriptCollection)
        {
           _newFileResult = CheckOutResults.CheckOutResultFiles(_checkOutFile, BatteryLocation, SelectedMachine.Machine);
           ScriptCollectionTemp.Add(_newFileResult);
           t += 1;
           worker.ReportProgress(t);
        }
        //worker.ReportProgress(t);
    }
    void Worker_WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ScriptModel _checkOutFile in ScriptCollectionTemp)
        {
            _checkOutFile.BackGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        }

        ScriptCollection = ScriptCollectionTemp;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified my code as follows and it works the second time through now.

```
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        ScriptModel _newFileResult = new ScriptModel();
        ObservableCollection<ScriptModel> _scriptCollectionTemp = new ObservableCollection<ScriptModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ScriptCollection.Count; i++ )
        {
            _newFileResult = CheckOutResults.CheckOutResultFiles(ScriptCollection[i], BatteryLocation, SelectedMachine.Machine);
            _scriptCollectionTemp.Add(_newFileResult);
            worker.ReportProgress(_scriptCollectionTemp.Count);
        }
        ScriptCollection = _scriptCollectionTemp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No control will like you changing them on a different thread to the UI thread. This is just the way the world works

Disregarding other problems, this pattern will allow you to update the UI from a different context than the UI Context

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
     () =>
        {
           // do any UI updates here
        });
```

Comment: I still don't see why it works the first time and gives an error the second time.  I would expect it to fail or work every time the same way.  Thanks for the answer I will give it a try.